# UTC time zone validation in drf

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How can I validate/force user to input the UTC time format. ie user should enter only the datetime in the below format only

> 2018-04-16T14:18:15Z

I am using the DateTimeField() in the serializer. Their I tried the option

`end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]).`

But I am getting the serializer validation error

> "end_date": [
>       "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."   ]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#date-and-time-fields).

It says that `input_formats` should be:

> A list of strings representing the input formats which may be used to
>   parse the date

Try passing `input_formats=['YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ']` or `['iso-8601']`

Also you may want to try and set `format` as well.

Comment: That is what I have done exactly there . Please have look into my descriprion

Comment: Oh OK, there are no quotes in the example so I thought that might be the problem. What happens if you use `['iso-8601']`? I know it's not exactly the format you're looking for but does it work at all?

Comment: By default it is iso-8601